# October cms error on install or update plugins from backend

Tags: php, laravel, curl, octobercms

I have a problem on October CMS, when I click "check for updates" or "install plugin" in the backend settings.

"Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION - assumed 'CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION'" on line 483 of /var/www/html/vendor/october/rain/src/Network/Http.php

Help me please if you know!Thank you everyone!!

In my `etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini` and `etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`  file `open_basedir` and `safe_mode` is  `Off`
But don't work Install plugins on backend.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution, 
Here are the steps to take:
 On SSH server

> Blockquote

1. `$ apt update`
2. `$ sudo apt install php(Your_php_version)-curl`
3. `$ service apache2 restart`

Thank you!